# PYTHON: Inserting all lines into array/list after specific symbol

Tags: python, arrays, list

Im having a little problem: I have .txt file which looks like this:

```
Random heading
----------
John
20

----------
Jack
18
```

I want to add this information into list/array like this:

```
`listName = [['John', '20'], ['Jack', '18']]`
```

So "----------" would be specific symbol to separate list items.

Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking for help you need to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s="""Random heading
----------
John
20

----------
Jack
18"""

print([x.split() for x in s.split("----------")])

[['Random', 'heading'], ['John', '20'], ['Jack', '18']]
```

You can skip the header with `next(file_object)` and split the remainder.

```
with open(infile) as f:
   header = next(f)
   spl = (x.split() for x in f.read().split("----------")[1:])
   for line in spl:
       print(line)
  ['John', '20']
  ['Jack', '18']
```

If you always have just two lines in each section:

```
lines = [[line.rstrip(), next(f).rstrip()] for line in f if line[0] != "-" and line.strip()]
```

And if they are always after the "-":

```
lines = [[next(f).rstrip(), next(f).rstrip()] for line in f if line[0] == "-"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as I wanted.